# Server response doesn't match the list size

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I have a Server developped in Spring Framework.

When i try to control the response by the browser web pasting the url, seems that the List (Response.java's field) has the right size (that is the same of the list returned from method getFourMyObject() ), i've also tried to print in the server's console the size and it's not equal to 1.

But when I get the response from my Android application, it doesn't recognize the other MyObject but the first.

So in the controller's Server the response's list has a different size from the received size from client.

My server's code:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RouteController extends RestGatewaySupport {

@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index (){
    return "index";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/objectize",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Response objectize(@RequestParam(value="time", defaultValue="-1") String time,
                                                 @RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue="-1") String id,
                                            @RequestParam(value="ratio", defaultValue="-1") String destination) {
    return new Response().addAllMyObjects(MyObject.getFourMyObject());
}
```

Response.java:

```
public class Response implements Serializable{
   public final List<MyObject> response;
   public Response () {
     this .response = new ArrayList<>();
    }
   public Response addmObect(MyObject mObject){
     this .response.add(mObject);
    return this;
   }
   public Response addAllMyObjects (List<MyObject> mObjects){
     this .response.addAll(mObjects);
    return this;
   }
```

}

Android app's requester method:

```
   protected List<Route> doInBackground(String... params) {
          String link = params[0];
          URL url;
          try {
              url = new URL(link);
              InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
              StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;

              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                  jsonData.append(line).append("\n");
              JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData.toString());
              JSONArray jsonMyObjects = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
              Log.i("logger","jsonMyObjects list's size = "+jsonMyObjects.length());
            return jsonMyObjects;



          } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
      }
```

Can someone help me?
It's a wrong parsing problem?

Comment: `the size and it's !=1.` ??? What do you mean? That the size is not one? Well what is it instead? Or what should it be? And which array are you talking about?

Comment: I have edited. I meant the List's size (a field of Response.java) that implemented was an ArrayList, sorry.
Can you help me?

Comment: Not in this way. Still unclear: `has the right size, i've also tried to print in console the size and it's not equal to 1.`. Then what is the right size?

Comment: Unclear: `it doesn't recognize the other element but the first.`. Which elements are you talking about? And if the server sends a number of array entries then how much do you teceive to begin with?

Comment: The elements of the list. 
List in my case has 4 elements, but android app detects just the first of this list.

Comment: Just log your jsonData string, you probably will see the problem.